# Node.js automatic GET requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cron, automation

I need to do a GET request and add to a mongoDB every 10 minutes in my node app.

I'm relatively new to node, and currently have to visit /myurl to initiate the process(GET and add to DB), which works as expected.

What would be the best method to have the node app constantly make this GET request(every 10 mins-ish)?

My research has led me to things like:

- JavaScript: var t=setInterval(runFunction,1000);
- Cron job. I'm not sure if it's possible to have a cron job execute a node function. Maybe this needs to be done outside of node.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using node, I'd use setInterval:

```
var t = setInterval(runFunction, 10 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but why do I need to set i to the variable 't'?

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but why do I need to set it to the variable 't'?  

For some reason I can't get it to work that way. It only logs once.  

This works:  

`setInterval(logTime, 10 * 60 * 1000);`  
`function logTime() {`  
   `console.log('hi');`  
`}`

Comment: Assigning to 't' should have no effect -- your test code should work just as well. However, if you have additional code that is calling clearInterval(t), then that will cancel the periodic calls.

Comment: Strange. Yeah, assigning to 't' gives me:

'listening on port 3000

timers.js:252
    callback.apply(this, args);
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)'

Comment: You are probably already using 't' for some other purpose. Try changing the name to 'intervalID'.

Comment: Bingo. Someday I'll start thinking like a programmer :P.